# Problema al reflejar cambios en un proyecto de simfony 2

Tags: php, ubuntu, twig

que tal. estoy tratando de visualizar los cambios que realizo en un proyecto de simfony 2, lo tengo en un ambiente de linux lite (virtualizado), con la versio de php 7.1.33

Ya le di los permisos que se requieren para la carpeta con la escritura.

Hize un cambio de un titulo, pero al ingresar al sistema este no me refleja nada.

Arranco el servidor con:

> `php app/console server:run`

este se visualiza ingreso las credenciales. entro a la seccion donde hize el cambio pero nada.

eh ejecutado estos dos comandos.

```
sudo rm -fr app/cache/*
sudo rm -fr app/logs/*
```

pero sigo sin ver los cambios.
Este es el cambio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que me sigue dando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que es lo que estaria pasando, espero su ayuda.

Comment: click derecho, inspeccionar elemento y mira lo generado en el HTML :D

Comment: @fredyfx gracias por el comentario

Comment: Vale, por cierto, ¿Has probado Control + F5 o reiniciar el server?

Comment: ya lo realice, pero sigue sin ningun efecto. reiniciando el server y limpiando el cache despues del cambio